# Splunk: Trying to join two searches so I can create delimters and format as a New Table

Tags: splunk

I am still very new to Splunk, but have learned enough to create reports using the "Extract Fields" option and using regex / delimeters to allow me to create custom extractions for Tables that I can create reports out of.

Right now I am trying to create a report for our Sales team to inform them when a user is basically using a process they should not be through our system, but am having problems on reporting on them properly. Ive tried using a search using an OR statement to try and join the searches that I am getting, but I noticed that the fields I am extracting duplicate information and the tables don't get joined properly.

Below is an example of two different searches that I am joining so I can get the following outcome after creating extracted fields

_Date/ Time and _Raw are already given and I know how to use extractions and "AS" statements to rename my extracted fields if need be. I will be performing a "-_Raw" as the reports and alerts that I am configuring will not be needed by the end party.

| _Date/Time | Corp_acct_nbr | LoginId | Product Ordered | _Raw

Below are my two searches that I need to "Join"

Search 1:

2019-03-29 08:07:14,833 [http-bio-8081-exec-21] INFO  {requestId=4e639bde-5234-11e9-9dc1-0050568edf8a, sessionId=dbe4a47e-522f-11e9-9dc1-0050568edf8a, loginId=bconnell, ipAddress=192.168.103.205} c.n.u.r.w.f.RequestContextFilter.doFilter:67 - Request /AccountService/billing/account/*3410061*/orderPayment completed in 12.880164272 seconds

Search 2:

2019-03-29 08:07:14,937 [http-bio-8081-exec-22] INFO  {requestId=4e639bde-5234-11e9-9dc1-0050568edf8a, sessionId=dbe4a47e-522f-11e9-9dc1-0050568edf8a, *loginId=bconnell*, ipAddress=192.168.103.205} c.p.RechargeEvent.createInvoice:1263 - ssnID ssnType<2> *Added hmItem to order.getHM: Analytics User $5*

both these have a host of ace02b-s01.nextiva.zone

My desired results would be

| _Date/Time | Corp_acct_nbr | LoginId | Product Ordered | 
    08:07:14      3410061         bconnell  Analytics User $5

I've italicized the fields as well above. I believe I can join these on the request ID as the transaction will always have a unique one. Any assistance is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the transaction command in your search, we have some [examples](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/Transaction#Basic_Examples) on our docs.

Your search would look something like `"... | transaction requestId maxspan=60s maxpause=5s"`. This will "join" each event with the same value for `requestId` into a single event which you can then feed into the `table` or `fields` commands to remove the fields you don't need.